# Transform `let` to `where`

Tags: haskell, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quicksort using `where`. In [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion#quick-sort) quicksort is implemented by using `let … in …`:

```
    quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
    quicksort [] = []
    quicksort (x:xs) =
    let smallerOrEqual = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
        larger = [a | a <- xs, a > x]
    in quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ quicksort larger
```

I have very similar version using `where` that doesn't work:

```
     quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
     quicksort [] = [] 
     quicksort (x:xs)
       | head(xs) >=x = head(xs):rightlist
       | otherwise = head(xs):leftlist
       where quicksort leftlist ++ x ++ quicksort rightlist

     rightlist :: (Ord a) => [a]
     leftlist :: (Ord a) => [a]
```

But my version gives me a parser error on the `where` line. Is it possible to implement quicksort using `where` instead of `let`?

Comment: The parse error is caused by `where quicksort(leftlist)++x++quicksort(rightlist)` being of the form `where expression` instead of the form `where definition`. That is, writing e.g. `where 2+2` instead of `where x = 2+2` will trigger the parse error.

Comment: Note that `head` is [evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) (more so if you write it out three times as part of the same expression). You should almost always trash `head xs`: replace the pattern where `xs` came from with `x':xs'` and simply use `x'`. But your logic is wrong anyway, you shouldn't be using `head xs` _at all_ here.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any possibility to implement quick sort using 'where' in stead of 'let'?

Yes.

```
let letDefines
in expression
```

is usually equivalent to

```
expression
where letDefines
```

So in your case we get

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) = quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ quicksort larger
    where
          smallerOrEqual = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
          larger = [a | a <- xs, a > x]
```

Comment: how can I avoid using list comprehension here?

Comment: @NicoMkhatvari: That's another question and should be posted as new one (don't edit additional questions into your post).

Answer (score 2):

The `where` clause defines functions or values for use in the main body of a function. In your code the `where` clause would be completely ignored even if it did parse because your guards immediately return a value and do not recurse.

```
quicksort (x:xs)
   | head(xs) >=x = head(xs):rightlist
   | otherwise = head(xs):leftlist
   where quicksort leftlist ++ x ++ quicksort rightlist
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
quicksort (x:xs) = if head(xs) >= x
                   then head(xs):rightlight
                   else head(xs):leftlist
```

Nothing in the `where` clause happens. If `rightlist` and `leftlist` are meant to be defined in your where clause then the code needs different formatting. As shown, your code ends after examining the first two elements. @Zeta does a nice job of explaining how to transform a let into a where.